# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

As the title states I need help fixing the cv2 module not found error.

I am able to import cv2 in cmd.However, cannot do so in vs code.
Even after to the changing to the 3.11.3 64-bit python interpreter, I keep getting the same "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'"

**Python and cv2 version from CMD:**

```
Python 3.11.3 (tags/....., Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2. __version__
'4.7.0'
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Compare `sys.path` between the interpreter where you can import the library and the one where you can't.

Comment: (btw, `cv2.__file__` is maybe more relevant/informative than `cv2.__version__`, though it's not enough to answer the problem without knowing `sys.path` in the interpreter from which you can't successfully load the library).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was able to figure out the issue. And resolve the problem

Comment: Great! If you think the way you resolved it will be helpful to others, write it up below (in the "Your Answer" section below -- clicking "Add an Answer" if you need to do that to get the option); otherwise, you might consider deleting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you can ensure that the package has been installed, it is likely due to an incorrect selection of the Python interpreter.

In VSCode, you can use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Python:Select Interpreter" to choose the correct python interpreter which you installed the package in.

BTW, creating virtual environment is a good choice to manage your python package.

Read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_python-environments) for more details.